# Press and hold for pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pyautogui

I'm using pygame and pyautogui to move the mouse around the screen in python 2.7. My code looks like:

```
    import pyautogui
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_mode()
    loop = True
    while loop:

         for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.quit:
                    pygame.quit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        pyautogui.moveRel(-50,0)
```

My code moves the mouse to the left when I press "a" but I have to repeatedly press the button when I want to move the mouse across the screen. Is there a way to be able to press and hold a and move the mouse across the screen? I've looked at other tutorials on this topic but they seem very project specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you want to do is set a variable indicating whether the key is down on keydown and update it once key is up.

Here, I updated your code to do just that as it might be easier to understand.

```
import pyautogui
import pygame
loop = True

a_key_down = False                                    # Added variable
while loop:

     for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.quit:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    a_key_down = True                 # Replaced keydown code with this
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:            # Added keyup
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    a_key_down = False                
    if a_key_down:                                    # Added to check if key is down
         pyautogui.moveRel(-50,0)
```

Comment: I imagine you want to put that `if a_key_down` in the while loop, not within the `for event in pygame.event.get()`. Otherwise it will cause a move to happen based on the number of events. Granted, this change would still make the movement dependent on the game loop rate, and I'm sure that's something that the OP will need to deal with...